# Entering the correct Publisher and Editor in a BibTex citation

Tags: citations, bibtex

I would like to enter a PDF book I have purchased into a bibtex library using JabRef. JabRef requires the publisher and editor information for "Book" type entries. In the inside cover of my book I see the following useful information:

> Academic Press is an Imprint of Elsevier
>
> *Library of Congress Cataloguing-in-Publication Data* A catalog record for this book is available from the Library of Congress
> *British Library Cataloguing-in-Publication Data* A catalogue record for this book is available from the British Library
> *Publisher:* Glyn Jones
> *Acquisition Editor:* Glyn Jones
> *Editorial Project Manager:* Naomi Robertson
> *Production Project Manager:* Kiruthika Govindaraju
> *Designer:* Christian Bilbow

Some more information about the book can be found in [this link](https://www.elsevier.com/books/the-material-point-method/zhang/978-0-12-407716-4)

I am inclined to place Elsevier as the editor and Academic Press as the Publisher. I also know that that Academic Press is owned by Elsevier. I have looked up the individuals stated in the Editorial Project Manager and the Publisher sections and they seem to work for Elsevier at this time. However I also note that Tsinghua University Press is mentioned in the cover of the book so I am not sure what their role was and whether they need to be included in the citation.

What should I place in the Editor and Publisher fields in JabRef, respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The label *editors* refers to human individuals, while the *publisher* is always a company.

**First, the editors**: In the context of a book, it only makes sense to talk about 'editors' if the book is an edited volume. Otherwise the people who wrote the book are 'authors'. - - In your case, there do not seem to be any 'editors' at all, but only 'authors' (X.Z., Z.C., and Y.L.). Are you sure that the editors-field is mandatory?

**Secondly, the publisher**: Formally, yes, the publisher is *Elsevier*, but if it uses an imprint (here: *Academic Press*), then you should name the imprint. Do not name the overarching company of the imprint. A publisher can use various imprints in order to circulate books under various trade names (each with different reputations and specificities); to a publisher, the *name* of the imprint is really one of the main purposes of using an imprint. Therefore, list the imprint (*Academic Press*), and not the overarching company (*Elsevier*).

(Why *Tsinghua University Press* is mentioned in the cover, I do not know; it might have something to do with [Elsevier's co-publishing agreement with Tsinghua Univ. Press](https://www.elsevier.com/about/press-releases/corporate/elsevier-signs-co-publishing-agreement-with-tsinghua-university-press).)

Comment: In JabRef the editor label is mandatory but it doesn't complain if I leave it blank... strange